# How do I display/render image from mongoDB with react native?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, expo

I have been researching and trying many solutions I could think of;

I want to render or display my images from my MongoDB Atlas Server to my react native app. I have done the backend work using multer to get file req and save it on my ../assets/ folder but when I try to fetch it and use <Image source={{uri: photo}}/> it either blank or shows a number e.g 22.

This is my file path after multer and saved in my MongoDB

```
../assets/15985061325795950a472-5363-43b7-851e-e2afab049d0f.jpg
```

This is my  Tag

```
<Image source={photo} style={styles.image} borderRadius={10} />
```

I get blank screens; I tried using require() but it requires a String, not {photo}.

I am using Expo-Client.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Are you saving files locally to ../assets/ folder? or it is a reference to your server directory?

Comment: Yes files are stored locally but the image paths are from my Db, they are dynamically populated.

Comment: since you can not use require, you have to explicitly embed the assets and then reference accordingly.

Comment: oh, please any example?

Answer (score 1):

From you photo path:

```
 ../assets/15985061325795950a472-5363-43b7-851e-e2afab049d0f.jpg
```

it seems that you are storing the image files locally after fetching. so for the local image files we have to use source={**require('localPath')**}.

so you should try

```
 <Image source={require('localPath')} />
```

Comment: I am looping every image from the parent component and pass the image value to its children component which is {photo} the images are dynamically populated, applying to require("localPath") might vary but require({photo}) do not accept photo been passed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<Image source={require('your path')} />
```

Comment: my paths are dynamically populated so its not possible to using require('my path') or just `<Image source={photo} />`

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the full path of your picture location since it's not on your project folder. in the `URL` in your image component it's something like

```
<image
source={{ uri: SERVER_IP + '/assets/15985...049d0f.jpg' }}
/>
```

so `SERVER_IP` can be like `yourwebsite.com` or `127.0.0.1:3000` if you are still in local. and remove the `..`